# Integration of exponential function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

> S(t)=e<sup>(-k*t)</sup> - is the function -
>
> ∫[0,∞] e<sup>(-k*t)</sup> dt - this should be the integration -
>
> = 1/k - and this should be the answer -

And I tried this but it didn't work and I didn't find any solutions.

```
from scipy import integrate
import sympy
import numpy as np

S = lambda t: np.exp(-k*t)
print(integrate.quad(S, 0, np.inf))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix numpy, scipy, and sympy like that. Just keep it in sympy:

```
from sympy import Symbol, integrate, exp, pprint

k = Symbol('k') 
t = Symbol('t')
integ = integrate(exp(-k*t),t)
pprint(integ)
```